# loading new jQuery from html files while using history API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modernizr

A couple of questions here...

**1.** So, I've created a site where all of the pages are loaded dynamically with the History API and Modernizr. I have this code stored in a file called `main.js` which I link to in everyone of my HTML files. This is my code from the History API.

```
$(function() {

    if(Modernizr.history){

    var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $(".container"),
    $pageWrap    = $(".wrapper"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    _link = $(this).attr("href");
    history.pushState(null, null, _link);
    loadContent(_link);
    return false;
    });

    function loadContent(href){
    $mainContent
            .fadeOut(500, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(href + "#content", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(500, function() {
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    console.log(href);
                    $("nav a[href$="+href+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
    }

    }

    });
```

And here is my basic markup for each of the HTML files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<title>About</title>

<!-- stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<!-- / stylesheets -->

<!-- scripts --> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/main.js"></script>
<!-- / scripts -->

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<header>
<nav class="menu">
  <a href="../">Home</a>
  <a href="../about">About The Film</a>
  <a href="../videos">Videos</a>
  <a href="../photos">Photos</a>
  <a href="/" class="current">Featuring</a>
</nav><!-- / .menu -->

</header>

<section id="featuring" class="container">
</section><!-- / #featuring -->

</div><!-- / .wrapper -->  

<script id="page-script"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have been storing jQuery in the footer with the id `#page-script`, and the problem I am running into is this. When I load a new page, I need to add the javascript in `#page-script` to the DOM. For example, one of the pages includes an image gallery running on the cycle 2 plugin, and another is a videos page using magnific popup, and I need the JS to refresh so that the plugins can be initiated without conflict when a user clicks on a nav link to load a new page. Does anyone know how to make it work so that it removes the current `#page-script` jQuery and adds the new jQuery to the DOM to make the plugins work properly?

**2.** Next question, when I load a new page, it's doubling up the navigation menu. This wouldn't be a big problem, but the navigation has a partially transparent background and when it adds the new navigation it's making the menu darker. Any thoughts on this as well?

I know there's a lot here, but everyone one here is a ninja, so I know I can get some help.

Thanks in advance!

Jesse

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't use JQuery's helper getscript(). There is a nice write-up about it here: http://davidwalsh.name/loading-scripts-jquery. This will allow you to dynamically inject your plugins (e.g. cycle 2) as required. You can just put a condition in your "loadContent()" function to check what page is requested and invoke a library etc.

Comment: @Pete well, I got it working to a point by adding `$(body).remove('#page-script').load('#page-script')` to the `delegate` function, but it's throwing off the animation/fades on the main content. The plugins run without conflict that way, but it does mess up the animations.